# how can chart js call datasets base on value from select option?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, chart.js

I'm trying to get value from select option dynamically then use the value to create new chart depend on value.

Doesn't work:

```
new Chart(context).Bar(callchart);
```

But this works:

```
new Chart(context).Bar(keyboard);
```

when you call it statically.

```
<select>
    @foreach($item_name as $in)
      <option id="{{$in->item_name}}" value="{{$in->item_name}}">{{$in->item_name}} </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
<canvas id="graph" width="800px" height="400px"></canvas>
```

```
var Mouse= {
labels:  ['January','February','March'],

datasets: [
    {
      fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
      pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      data: [30,120,90]
    },
]
};

var keyboard = {
labels: ['March', 'Apr', 'May'],

datasets: [
    {
      fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
      pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      data: [50,100,140]
    },
]
};


var Spoon ={
labels: ['June', 'July', 'August'],

datasets: [
    {
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [1,2,3]
    },
]
};

var context = document.querySelector('#graph').getContext('2d');

if(window.bar != undefined)
  window.bar.destroy(); 

window.bar = new Chart(context).Bar(keyboard);

$("select").on('change', function() {
  //GETING VALUE FROM SELECT OPTION
  var callchart =this.value; 
  var context = document.querySelector('#graph').getContext('2d');
  if(window.bar != undefined)
    window.bar.destroy(); 
  //CREATING CHART USING VALUE FROM SELECT OPTION
  window.bar = new Chart(context).Bar(callchart);
});

</script>
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Hi Jer,  we are missing some info here: You are setting `callchart` to `this.value`. What is the content of this.value?

Comment: Opps sorry, this.value has the value of selected option value

Comment: Well...ofcourse it does...But what IS the value?

Comment: can you do `console.log(callchart)` before setting the `window.bar` and show us what you got?